# Program stops working when making big table (2'000'000+)

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error, primes

I wrote this program using Sieve of Eratosthenes. It is supposed to output prime numbers up to 2'500'000, but it crashes when trying to create array bigger than ~2'100'000. Any ideas what might be broken?

Compiling with gcc in Code::Blocks (Windows 8.1, shame on me).

PS It works flawless for N <= 2'000'000

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Input
    long n;
    scanf("%ld", &n);

    // Initialize vars
    bool number[n+1];
    for(long i = 0; i < n; i++)
        number[i] = false;

    // Main loop
    for(long i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {
        if(number[i]) // If number is already removed
            continue; // Do next number

        // Remove x * i
        for(long j = i*2; j <= n; j += i)
            number[j] = true;
    }

    // Print
    for(long i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        if(!number[i]) printf("%ld ", i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
bool number[n+1];
```

Try either `std::vector<bool> number(n+1)` or `bool* number = new bool[n+1]`

Comment: Had to wait 8 minutes :P

Comment: Note that the "working" line also causes a memory leak.  Probably not problematic in this use case, where `main()` immediately exits taking the memory with it.  But good to be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid C++, if `n` is not a constant integral expression (yours isn't):

```
bool number[n+1];
```

It is a g++ extension, and puts the array on the call stack, which has limited size.  You're overflowing it, causing an immediate program crash (no exception to recover from) so this is a bad idea even in g++.

Try

```
std::vector<bool> number(n+1);
```

(Note you'll need `#include <vector>` to make that work)

Also note that `vector<bool>` is a weird beast.  Should work just fine for your usage, but to get something closer to `bool[]`, you can also try

```
std::vector<char> number(n+1);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `even in g++`. What is that implying about g++?

Comment: @BWG There is no implying here, a g++ expansion makes it possible but even with this extension its not a good thing to do o.O

Comment: @BWG: I mean that other compilers will reject that outright.  g++ will try to make it work but failure then occur silently at runtime, so even if you have g++ (which accepts these C99-style VLAs) you should not use them.

Comment: If anything, what I'm implying is that **g++ support for VLAs is a bug not a feature**.  There, I said it clearly.

Comment: and what do you mean by "vector<bool> is a weird beast" please? I thought `vector<bool>` was automatically bit-packed (taking 8x less space than `vector<char>` of same length).

Comment: @Will: Yes, it is, via template specialization.  And it also does not meet the container requirements.

Comment: @WillNess: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670308/alternative-to-vectorbool and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15617501/103167 and http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool

Comment: OK, for the benefit of other readers, the refs say *"`vector<bool>` is not a container as its reference and pointer types are not references and pointers."*

Comment: And because access to different elements can still be a conflict (in the threading sense)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to allocate array of n bools on stack, which might be simply to small. Try allocating on heap with std::vector or new operator.